# Strange clientHeight behaviour for image

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

I have a function which is working in firefox:

```
function widthimg() {
           var wheight = document.getElementById('recent-img1');
           console.log(wheight.clientHeight);
           document.getElementById('recent-img2').style.height = wheight.clientHeight +'px';
                    }
```

but not in chrome, chrome shows no image at all (a image with 0 height).

Weird thing is, both elements are images:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 margin-top-60 zoominmouse">
  {{HTML::image('images/recentprojects1.png','recent',array('class' => 'img-responsive img-center image-popup-vertical-fit', 'id' => 'recent-img1')) }}
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 margin-top-60 zoominmouse" id="test">
  {{ HTML::image('images/pricing1.png','recent',array('class' => 'img-responsive img-center image-popup-vertical-fit', 'id' => 'recent-img2')) }}
</div>
```

So, as firefox reads out the property of wheight.clientHeight I thought I give this a try:

```
function widthimg() {
           var wheight = document.getElementById('recent-img1');
           console.log(wheight.clientHeight);
           document.getElementById('recent-img2').clientHeight = wheight.clientHeight;
                    }
```

as I now pass clientHeight to clientHeight, which makes sense for me, but this works in none of both browsers.

So my 3 questions are:

- What can I do to make the function working in chrome?
- Why can't I pass clientHeight to clientHeight?
- Is there a possibility to make both of the images the height of img1 with css?

Comment: clientHeight is read-only, just use height

Comment: @dandavis just height doesn't work.

Comment: height has to work, and it's R/W to boot... whatever the prop, make sure the image is loaded before measuring...

Comment: call your method onload and it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be use like this:

```
function widthimg() {
    var wheight = document.getElementById('recent-img1');
    console.log(wheight.clientHeight);
    document.getElementById('recent-img2').clientHeight = wheight.clientHeight;
    console.log(document.getElementById('recent-img2').clientHeight);
             }

<body onload="widthimg()">
// rest of your html
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should get img1 height only after the image has loaded, so you can set img2 height as

```
img1.onload = function() {
    img2.height = img1.height;
}
```

Comment: i couldn't have said it better.